# .net SSL error when authenticating request

Tags: .net-core

I'm configuring my API to authenticate api requests by WSO2 tokens. However my debug wso2 is running on localhost and returns an SSL error. Is there a way to ignore invalid certificates in debug?

I found some questions about this, but I could not get the AddOAuth2Introspection to use a different httpclient with this validation disabled.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OAuth2IntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOAuth2Introspection(opt =>
{
    opt.Authority = "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token";
    opt.ClientId = "N3JL60s_EyYZgZ6Ev0QQ9sAh3RAa";
    opt.ClientSecret = "_r2My_fHNBKBoNpbxiZ47hBaO3ka";
    opt.SkipTokensWithDots = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(OAuth2IntrospectionDefaults.BackChannelHttpClientName)
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new SocketsHttpHandler
        {
            SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
            {
                RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
            }
        };
    });
```